# create and append multiple elements with data from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Let **data** be a JSON,
what I am trying here is appending multiple elements according to the data from JSON to the div ,
`<div class="studentTab" ></div>`. How can I achieve this ?
(nb: please consider that we have 2 Languages and 2 Specializations)

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        var html = '<div class="dtls">' +
                            '<a href="profile.html" target="_blank"></a>' +
                            '<h4 class="verified">' + data.student[0].firstName + '</h4 >' +
                            '<ul>' +
                            '<li>' + data.student[0].location + '</li>' +
                            '<li>' + data.student[0].mark + ' /hour</li>' +
                            '<li>' + data.student[0].year+ ' accademic year</li>' +
                            if (data.student[0].Languages != null)
                                            {
                                var lang = string.Join(",", data.student[0].Languages.Select(it => it.Name));
                                                <li>lang </li>
                            }
                            if (data.student[0].Specializations.length > 1)
                            {
                                var rcount = data.student[0][index].Specializations.length - 1;
                                <li>data.student[0].Specializations[0].Name + rcount more</li>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <li>data.student[0].Specializations[0].Name</li>
                            }
                            '</ul>' +
                            '</div>'
                        $('#studentTab').append(html);
                    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use map() for solving such problem. Please make check:

- If your 'data' is underfined or not;
- Better save your data.student[0] in some variable;
- You never know how many objects inside of data you have. Probably some times is underfined due to network errors or more or less objects due to some back-end updates

Comment: could you please provide an example ?